# eWAM - Uppercasing a string value

Tags: ewam

I'm looking to make a simple function to make a string uppercase in eWAM. Here's what I've got, but it throws an error.

```
procedure CapitalizeName
    var lowercaseName : CString
    var uppercaseName : CString

    lowercaseName = 'test'
    uppercaseName = ToUpper(lowercaseName)
endProc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Upcase` is the proper function to use:

```
procedure CapitalizeName
   var lowercaseName : CString
   var uppercaseName : CString

   lowercaseName = 'test'
   uppercaseName = Upcase(lowercaseName)
endProc
```